# how to get foursquare uid from token based authetication?

Tags: foursquare

I'm using Token Flow as described here https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth

User authenticates foursquare and is sent to a callback page on my server from which I parse the access token for that user out of the url.

Once i have this access token, how do I look up the user so I can grab her uid?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the [/users/USER_ID](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/users) endpoint with user id "self" to get information about the acting user.